# Timestamp format on row_to_json

Tags: json, postgresql, string-formatting

Consider `tableA` which has column `row_added_dttm` of type `timestamp without timezone`. The actual value is `2017-08-31 18:34:42.813175`.

After I executed the below query, it results in a timestamp with timezone like `{"crt_dttm":"2017-08-31T18:34:42.813175"}`.

```
select row_to_json(t) from (select row_added_dttm from tableA limit 1) as t;
```

But the format which I require is something like `2017-08-31T18:34:42.813Z`. I am not sure how to generate that, please help. Using `row_to_json` is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to influence the format used by `row_to_json`.

You could define a view on your table and use

```
to_char(row_added_dttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS"Z"')
```

to format the `timestamp` as a string.

Then you can use `row_to_json` on that view to get your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I changed query to select row_to_json(t) from (select to_char(row_added_dttm,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS"Z"') as row_added_dttm from tableA limit 1) as t;
This resulted required result.